# Как в php строку умножить на число?

Tags: php, php5

К примеру хочу строку `"aaa"` умножить на число `3`, чтобы было `"aaaaaaaaa"`.

Но вместо этого `"aaa"` преобразуется в число (т.е. `0`), потом умножается.

Явное указание типа делает тоже самое:
`(string)"aaa"*(int)3` выводит `0`.

Возможно ли увеличить строку несколько раз умножением?

Comment: Нельзя. И возведением в степень тоже нельзя. И операцией деления  поделить строку пополам тоже нельзя! Пичалька...

Comment: @PinkTux как насчёт факториала строки? )

Answer (score 6):

Ясно что перемножить строку нельзя.
Используйте [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-repeat.php):

```
var_dump(str_repeat("aaa", 3)); // string(9) "aaaaaaaaa"
```